# Save selected fields in MongoRepository spring without affecting others

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongotemplate, spring-mongo

There is a mongo collection with lots of nested fields in it.
Since it would be too tedious to map each member in @Data classes. I had added just the members I need to use

```
@Data
@Document
public class MyCollection {

    @Id
    private String id;
    String code;
    String code;
}
```

My MongoRepository class looks like this

@Repository
public interface MyCollectionRepository extends MongoRepository {

```
MyCollection findById(String id);
```

}

Now I want to update the code field in my collection.
So I updated the code field in the entity and did

```
myCollection = mongoRepository.findById(1)
myCollection.setCode("newCode")
mongoRepository.save(myCollection)
```

Now problem is all the other fields in the database that I did not include in my entity got removed.

How can I update a selected field without affecting the others. I don't want to individually map all the members of the collection to my @Data class as it is too huge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom repository and in implementation of that repository, use mongoTemplate to update selected fields like this.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(1));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("code", "newCode");

mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, MyCollection.class);
```

This will use MongoDb's `$set` operator to set only provided fields without modifying other fields.

Comment: How do I create the mongoTemplate object?

Comment: By Injecting it using ```@Autowired```. check this reference - https://blog.marcnuri.com/spring-data-mongodb-custom-repository-implementation/

Comment: How can I update a list of records. Shoul I iterate over them and do or is there a better way?

Comment: you can use ```BulkWriteOperation```